webrtc, how to createAnswerSdp without m=video?
I am using JSSIP to implement WebRTC phone, and I have an trouble when a video call comes in (the SDP contains m=video). I want create SDP to contain only audio,not m=video.But always createAnswer sdp have m=video and a=recvonly.
some SIP phone like MicroSIP and Linphone can answer with only audio.
Is there no api to return only audio sdp with the WebRTC API? I see that the options in createAnswer has been deprecated, and offerToReceiveVideo is not useful. What should I do?
i try to add all possible parameter,but not effect.
And jssip google group has been banded, I don't know where to go and ask question
session.answer({
    rtcOfferConstraints: {
      offerToReceiveAudio: true,
      offerToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
      OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      mandatory: { OfferToReceiveAudio: true, OfferToReceiveVideo: false, offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: false }
    },
    rtcAnswerConstraints: {
      offerToReceiveAudio: true,
      offerToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
      OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      mandatory: { OfferToReceiveAudio: true, OfferToReceiveVideo: false, offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: false }
    },
    rtcConstraints: {
      offerToReceiveAudio: true,
      offerToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      OfferToReceiveAudio: true,
      OfferToReceiveVideo: false,
      //@ts-ignore
      mandatory: { OfferToReceiveAudio: true, OfferToReceiveVideo: false, offerToReceiveAudio: true, offerToReceiveVideo: false }
    },

    mediaConstraints: {
      audio: true,
      video: false
    },

    sessionTimersExpires: 180
  })

